# Add first option in KendoDropdownList to be null and selected while its in KendoGrid

Tags: kendo-ui

When i add

```
$("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList").one("open", function() {
            $(this.ul[0]).unshift("<li tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"option\" unselectable=\"on\" class=\"k-item\" data-offset-index=\"0\">---</li>");
});
```

and in kendoDropDownList option its not working

```
optionLabel: {
    DDName: "---",
    DDID: null
},
```

Then its add but selected two options and send in REQ last one, if some other solutions i think that this is not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I don't know why you are sending over a complex object into the label, which is a string.

```
$("#ddlTest").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: " -- Select -- "
}).data("kendoDropDownList").one(...).select(0).;
```

Comment: If you are using custom template, you have to send object to optionLabel. However you are right, in this scenario should be your example enough.

Comment: Sry, but its working only if this not in grid, but when i put in grid same control then problem occur after i try to edit list  automatically select and remove input options and shows only  " -- Select -- ", thank you